# a string in C++ with a null byte

Tags: c++

I have a question about a string in C++. what will happen if the null byte goes one index further?
as shown below.

```
char name [10] = "Jack";

0   1   2   3   
J | a | c | k |

name [5] = '\0';
```

this is states in my homework. extra null kludge.

Comment: Depends what you then do with `name`.

Comment: Hint: the string literal `"Jack"` already has a null terminator in it.

Comment: yes, but what if I want to set the null after the name with one index as sown above?

Comment: @user1318393: Then... you will have another null terminator at index 5. So? As far as your computer is concerned it's just a sequence of numbers. What it means is up to you.

Answer (score 6):

What do you mean by "what will happen"?

According to what you wrote, you are simply creating an array of 10 positions, filling the firsts 5 positions with `Jack\0`, then assigning `\0` to the sixth. Every function that works with strings will treat it exactly the same way, since strings usually end with `\0`.

Comment: I mean the length of the string will stay 4? or it will change to 5 since I added the null to index 5.

Comment: @user1318393: Depends on what you mean by "length of the string". If the length of the string is defined as the number of non-null characters before the null terminator (which is how `strlen()` works), then the length stays the same. Some string representations allow for null characters to appear in the string itself; in that case you would've increased the length from 4 to 5. It's meaningless to ask "how long is this string" without talking about how it's represented. There are some string representations where two null chacters in a row actually means something significant.

Comment: @user1318393 In your example your string does not coincide with your array. When you assign `"Jack"` you are already putting `\0` in the fifth position. You can modify every element past the end of your string and this will not affect your "string". Unless you modify the fifth position (removing the `\0`), your string will keep having length 4 (at least, according to the common meaning of "length of a string").